# i have arraylist of buyers and each buyer had a name and price

Tags: java, arraylist

how can I read all the buyers from file and store all of buyers in an array list? how can i do this?

```
 public ArrayList<Bidder> ListOfBidder = new ArrayList<Bidder>();
 File Bidder =new File("E:\\Bidder.txt");
 public void getListFromFille() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
     Scanner in = new  Scanner(Bidder);
     Bidder b=new Bidder();   
     while(in.hasNextLine())
     {
         b.BName=in.nextLine();
         b.BPrice=in.nextInt(); 
         ListOfBidder.add(b);
     }

     in.close();
 }
```

it gives me this error: `Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException`

Comment: Have you looked up what the error is? The error states `Thrown by a Scanner to indicate that the token retrieved does not match the pattern for the expected type, or that the token is out of range for the expected type.` This should indicate where the problem lies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have your class `Bidder` implement `Serializable`, you can then use `ObjectOutputStream` to save a `Bidder` or an `ArrayList<Bidder>` to a file.  Then when you're ready to read those objects back in you can use `ObjectInputStream` to read them back in to objects.

```
 class Bidder implements Serializable{
     //class code
 }
```

Use these methods to save an `ArrayList<Bidder>` and then read it back in

```
 void saveBidders(ArrayList<Bidder> bidders, String file) throws IOException{

     ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new File(file));
     oos.writeObject(bidders);
     oos.close();
 }

 ArrayList<Bidder> getBidders(String file) throws IOException{

     ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new File(file));
     ArrayList<Bidder> bidders = (ArrayList<Bidder>) ois.readObject();
     ois.close();
     return bidders;
 }
```

Here is some documentation:

`Serializiable`
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html

`ObjectOutputStream`
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html

`ObjectInputStream`
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html

Comment: How is the bidder information being put into the file? Are you adding it in manually?  Or are you using the saveBidders method above?

Answer (score 0):

This Exception is usually  Thrown by a Scanner to indicate that the token retrieved does not match the pattern for the expected type, or that the token is out of range for the expected type.

Try this!!

```
 Scanner in = new  Scanner(Bidder);
Bidder b=new Bidder();   
while(in.hasNextLine())
{
b.BName=in.next();
in.nextLine();
b.BPrice=in.nextInt(); 
ListOfBidder.add(b);
}
```

Comment: but i cant get all the Bidders?